# What is the distribution of the 'achieved' $R^2$?

Tags: multiple-regression, linear-model, r-squared, non-central, quadratic-form

I am interested in the distribution of/performing inference on the 'achieved' $R^2$ coefficient in multiple linear regression. Suppose that $y\sim x\beta + \epsilon$ with $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0,\sigma^2\right)$, where $x$ is a $p$-vector. You observe $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ and corresponding $y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n$, with independent errors. You perform linear regression to get $\hat{\beta}$, and then compute the *sample* $R^2$ in the usual way: $R^2 = 1 - \frac{SS_\mbox{err}}{SS_{\mbox{tot}}}$. Nothing new here.

There are known methods for hypothesis testing the *population* analogue of $R^2$, as well as computing confidence intervals on it. (I am thinking of Lee's paper, and followups by Algina, O'Brien, *inter alios*). The population analogue is defined in terms of the (unknown) true regression coefficients $\beta$ and the true variance $\sigma^2$.

I am interested in the *achieved* $R^2$ which is the amount of variance explained by $\hat{\beta}$. Conditional on $x$ *and on* $\hat{\beta}$, I would define it as
$$
R^2_{\mbox{ach}} = 1 - \frac{\mbox{E}\left[\left(y - \hat{\beta}x\right)^2\right]}{\mbox{E}\left[\left(y-\bar{y}\right)^2\right]}.
$$
Clearly this is less than the *population* $R^2$, because the true $\beta$ minimizes $\mbox{E}\left[\left(y - \beta x\right)^2\right]$. I would guess it is less than the *sample* $R^2$ because that (usually) overestimates the population $R^2$.

I am having problems thinking about this quantity because it is both unobserved *and* random ($\hat{\beta}$ is a random variable.) I am guesing that, up to some transforms, I can represent this as a non-central chi-square, abusing $\hat{\beta}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\beta,\sigma^2\left(X^{\top}X\right)^{-1}\right)$, and noting that $\mbox{Var}\left[y - \hat{\beta}x\right] = \sigma^2 + \mbox{Var}\left[(\hat{\beta} - \beta)x\right]$, but I'm being dense and lazy. (Also, treating $x$ as fixed will later be generalized to $x$ being random.)

Is this is a well-known problem? For predicting future performance of a linear model, it would seem to be a more important quantity than the population $R^2$, for example.

Comment: Re "clearly this is less than": this statement appears to be equivalent to asserting that the OLS estimate of $\sigma^2$ is *biased*! Am I missing something here?

Comment: @whuber, hmm. the _achieved_ $R^2$ is computed in terms of the population parameters, so I'm not sure how the OLS estimate of $\sigma^2$ enters into it.

Comment: ahh, I see the confusion; the $\mbox{Var}$ is conditional on $x$ *and* $\hat{\beta}$. That is, I have run the regression, computed $\hat{\beta}$ and then will use the regression model 'out of sample'. I can see how this is confusing. edit coming.

Comment: the problem is that 'conditional on $x$' forces $y-\hat{\beta}x$ to be just a shift of $y$ and so $R^2_{\mbox{ach}}$ is just identically zero as defined. 
As noted, I will later have to consider $x$ as being normally distributed, in which case, I believe, the achieved $R^2$ as defined is no longer forced to be zero. bleah.